# Capturing Empty rows returned by ADO select query from Inno setup

Tags: ado, inno-setup

I am using ADO connection to connect to SQL from Inno setup, I am running some select query which i capture it to a variable, if the select query returns empty rows, it throws "Invalid variant type conversion" error. I am not sure if i can use the `VarIsNull` option and also how to use it in my code. Please help. Below is the sample code.

```
ADOCommand := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
 ADOCommand.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;
 SQLQuery := 'SELECT Name FROM sys.databases where name=''' + DBValue + '''';
 ADOCommand.CommandText := SQLQuery;
 ADOCommand.CommandType := adCmdText;
 ADORecordset := ADOCommand.Execute;
 Name := ADORecordset.Fields(0);
```

Comment: If the published code is the actual code of your installer, your problem is not the null field, but the recordset you're retrieving is empty if the database DBValue doesn't exist. Improve your question or post the real code you're having trouble with (or a _correct_ equivalent of that).

Comment: @jachguate, Thanks, have edited the question and yes this is the code im using..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if the returned record set is empty before assigning the value to the Name variable.

A empty recordset will return true for the EOF property just after you open it, in code it may look like this example:

```
  SQLQuery := 'SELECT Name FROM sys.databases where name=''' + DBValue + '''';
  ADOCommand.CommandText := SQLQuery;
  ADOCommand.CommandType := adCmdText;
  ADORecordset := ADOCommand.Execute;
  if ADORecordset.EOF then
  begin
    MsgBox('No records', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
    exit;
  end
  else begin
    Name := ADORecordset.Fields(0);
    MsgBox('Name ''' + Name + '''.', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
  end;
```

Comment: Avoid to use the ADO Command for fetching data (in other words, for SELECTs). Use [`Recordset::Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx) instead. And much better visible in code will be to query [`RecordCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx), or better to say, it is intended for getting record count. @anand, try to follow the [`ADO objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679836(v=vs.85).aspx) reference on MSDN; you will find there everything you need to know ;-)

Comment: Thanks TLama, will do tht :)